# Is it possible yet to use mint tokens supporting both transfer fees and confidential transfers?

Tags: spl-token, mint, token-2022

I can see in the documentation that Token-2022's transfer fees and confidential transfers are supported (or intended to be supported) when used together.  However, when I attempt to mint a token with both, like this:

```
spl-token --program-id TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb create-token --enable-confidential-transfers auto --transfer-fee 50 0
```

I receive the error message `Program log: Mint or account is initialized to an invalid combination of extensions`.

Looking at the source code for program-2022, I see that it checks to ensure that the `ConfidentialTransferFeeConfig` extension is loaded when confidential transfers and transfer fees are used together, but I don't see in the documentation or the CLI code how I could set the config expected at mint.

Am I overlooking something, or is this still incomplete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You found a bug! We're not automatically initializing the confidential transfer fee extension if the confidential transfer and transfer fee are provided.

If it lands, this will get fixed with https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/pull/5862, so if you pull from master and create a mint with a transfer fee and confidential transfers, it will properly work, ie:

```
$ spl-token create-token --transfer-fee 100 1000000 --enable-confidential-transfers auto
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not yet possible, you can find it here in the future work section:
https://spl.solana.com/token-2022/status

"Due to the transaction size limit, it is not possible to do confidential transfers with a fee. We plan to include that capability with Solana 1.18."

Comment: Since it is possible to mint a token supporting confidential transfers before the 1.17 upgrade enables use of the feature, I had hoped that it would be possible to mint a token supporting both prior to support in 1.18 even if the confidential transfers would be gated until the 1.18 upgrade.  But I certainly don't see the ability to do so.

Comment: it's weird that they allow it before being used on one side, but not on the other ! could you mark my answer as accepted please ? thanks !