# How to use "spl-token set-transfer-fee" CLI function in JS?

Tags: web3.js, spl-token-program, token-2022, cli

I noticed there is CLI function in SPL-token library for setting transfer fee but this function is missing from javascript SDK.

CLI:
https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/master/token/program-2022/src/extension/transfer_fee/instruction.rs#L404

JS:
https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/master/token/js/src/extensions/transferFee/instructions.ts (no function available)

Is it possible to send transaction manually to use rust function set_transfer_fee in JS?

If so, how? It would be probably something similar like calling Rust function from any program in general in js?

Comment: No, I do not really need confidental transfers. I am trying to build a TX where I set transfer fee to 0, make a transfer to some wallet and put transfer fee back to some value, all actions in one transaction. I can join multiple actions in JS but there is missing function for setting transfer fee for transfer fee extension in JS library.

Comment: My mistake it's this one: https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/7775/spl-token-2022-how-to-modify-transfer-fee-configuration-for-an-existing-mint

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible yet to use mint tokens supporting both transfer fees and confidential transfers?](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/8106/is-it-possible-yet-to-use-mint-tokens-supporting-both-transfer-fees-and-confiden)

Comment: Well apart from the same conclusion that there is missing function ins JS library there is no additional info I could use to solve my problem. There should be a way how to interact with any prgram and use any function in said program with web3js library no? Even without helper library.